# How to monitor progress of Oracle Materialized View

Tags: oracle

I have created a materialized view in Oracle 12.1 database. The master table has materialized view log created, so that I can do a fast refresh.

I have executed the refresh using DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH, but it is taking too much time.

I have verified network connectivity between two databases.

How can I troubleshoot the refresh process ?

Comment: Check this [link](https://techgoeasy.com/monitor-materialized-views-refresh/)